# How to do conditionally filtering with Directus Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, directus, headless-cms

#### Problem

I am not able to change the default `AND` operator in the `curl` call like explained in the *directus api docs*:

https://docs.directus.io/api/reference.html#filtering

#### Question

How can I enable the `OR` operator in order to filter based on different criteria like the code below?

#### Code

```
return client
      .getItems('privileges', {
        fields: ['*', 'image.filename', 'image.data.full_url', 'attachment.*', 'partner.*.*', 'location.*', 'category.*.*', 'type.icon.data.full_url'],
        meta: ['total_count', 'result_count'],
        sort: 'created_on',

    filter: {
      'location.city': {
        'contains': lowerQ
      },
      // 'location.title': {
      //   'contains': lowerQ
      // },
      category: {
        'eq': category,
      },
      available_from: {
        'lte': 'now'
      },
      available_until: {
        'gte': 'now'
      },
    },
    limit,
    offset,
  }).then(response => {
    dispatch(getPrivilegesSuccess(key, response))
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch(getPrivilegesFail(key, error))
  });
```

> So, the comments out code is a different criteria that should be able to match on inserted text using the *or* operator. Instead it is using the *AND* operator in the curl output api call at the moment.

Would appreciate any type of help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
filter: {
  field_one: {
    'eq': 'hello'
  },
  field_two: {
    'logical': 'or',
    'eq': 'world'
  },
},
```

Just add `'logical': 'or'` to the object you'd like to use as your 'OR'

Comment: WHy is the logical on the available_until?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you tell me where this is explained in the SDK docs?